# Javascript RegExp Check for Either String or Integer

Tags: javascript, regex

I need my regular expression to execute wether the incoming value is a string or an integer.
What I have only works with strings.
My Javascript is the following:

```
var regExp = new RegExp(valueToMatch, 'gi');
item.ssn.match(regExp)
```

The `valueToMatch` could be either a character that looks like "1" or `1`. So basically a string or an integer.

Comment: Soooo........ what's `valueToMatch`?

Comment: I got the Integer part but what do you mean if it is a string? Do you want to check the type of data?

Comment: I've made an update with some info.

Comment: You may simply use `regExp.test(s)`, or `regExp.test("" + s)` - the string will get  coerced to a string automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var passVal = typeof(valueToMatch) === 'number'? valueToMatch.toString() : valueToMatch
var regExp = new RegExp(passVal , 'gi');
item.ssn.match(regExp)
```

You should check the value before passing through regex expression.

Comment: what is 'number'?

Comment: `number` is Number is a numeric data type which is `integer` in this case. Have a look : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof